# python requests.get(url) with http 1.0 protocol

Tags: python, python-requests

i m trying to send request with http1.0 protocol using requests.get()
My code is as follows
requests.get(url,headers=headers,cookies=c2,timeout=60, verify=False)

for scraping i want to send an http 1.0 protocol how i can send using  requests()MODULE

Comment: can you show us more code and what url you are attempting to contact?

Comment: [*"Requests allows you to send organic, grass-fed **HTTP/1.1** requests"*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:858: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
M getting above error when i   try to make request